# Image uploading from web view in android

Tags: android, image, android-webview

I have created an android application using web view and following is my code

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    webView.loadUrl("http://aamirarif.com/tomnjoe/login.php");
```

Now , the problem is in my website there is an option of uploading image , that is the option which is not working when I open it from the android web view and no error is showing in log cat. My updated code is

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    webView.loadUrl("http://aamirarif.com/tomnjoe/login.php");

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
    if (null == mUploadMessage)
        return;
    Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
            : intent.getData();
    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
    mUploadMessage = null;

}
}

class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
// The undocumented magic method override
// Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType("image/*");
    WebViewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
}
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Add the Following code After  `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);` in your code.

Code is :

```
webView = new WebView(this);
```